# Need to compare folder path in VBS (.regex)

Tags: regex, vbscript, string-comparison

Question is: 
I need to compare `FOLDER1` path and `FOLDER2` path strings in VBS.

`FOLDER1` I read from text file, it was saved earlier. `FOLDER2` - from Select Folder dialog. 
I want to prevent user to choose `FOLDER2` if:
`FOLDER2 = FOLDER1`
`FOLDER2 = FOLDER1\some_folder`
`FOLDER2 = Parent_Folder\FOLDER1`

for example:
`Folder1 = c:\users\user\Documents`
then `Folder2` cannot be: `c:\users\user\Documents`, `c:\users\user\Documents\Letters` or `c:\users\user\`

Cannot make right regex to compare. Right now use the following code, but need normal solution.

```
    RightPath = 0
    Do

    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder:", &H10&, strPath)

        If objFolder Is Nothing Then
        msgbox "Configuration canceled" ,64 , "Information"
        Wscript.Quit
    End If

    Set objFolderItem = objFolder.Self
    objPath = objFolderItem.Path

    ' Right now, Check for users folder only
    RightPath = RightPath + 1
    Dim re, targetString
    Set re = New RegExp
    With re
      .Pattern = "Desktop|Documents|Downloads|Music|Pictures|Videos"
      .Global = False
      .IgnoreCase = True
    End With

    targetString = objPath
    If re.Test(targetString)  Then
        msgbox "You cannot choose:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf &  _
        "Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Music, Pictures or Videos" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
   "Please select another location" ,48 , "Warning!"
        RightPath = 0
    End If

    Loop Until RightPath > 0

    msgbox "You selected "+targetString ,0 , "Information,"
    Wscript.Quit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can't be any of these: `c:\users\user\Documents, c:\users\user\Documents\Letters` or `c:\users\user\` then `Instr` might help with the first two.

For example,

```
Folder1 = "c:\users\user\Documents"
Folder2 = "c:\users\user\Documents\Letters"
If InStr(Folder2,Folder1) Then FAIL
```

If you didn't want any part of the user input to be the same as Folder1 then you could reverse the order of the `InStr` check.

If you need to get more specific than this, you might have to split your Folder strings into arrays (split by "\") then compare the first x number of fields in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that only immediate parent and subfolders should be excluded (e.g. `FOLDER1\foo` is forbidden, but `FOLDER1\foo\bar` is allowed). If that assumption is correct, something like this should work:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set app = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

dir1 = LCase(fso.GetAbsolutePathName("C:\Users\user"))
parent1 = fso.GetParentFolderName(dir1)

Do
  Set fldr = app.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder:", &H10&, dir1)
  If fldr Is Nothing Then Exit Do  'user pressed [Cancel]

  dir2 = LCase(fldr.Self.Path)
  parent2 = fso.GetParentFolderName(dir2)
Loop Until dir1 <> dir2 And parent1 <> dir2 And dir1 <> parent2
```

Note that with the parameters you use for `BrowseForFolder` the user will only be able to select a folder below `dir1` unless he types a different path into the input field.